# Entity Framework selects too many columns in views

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

When I use Entity Framework against a SQL table, it only refers to the necessary columns in the generated SQL:

```
ctx.Types.Select(rdi => rdi.Name)
```

becomes

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Types] AS [Extent1]
```

However, if I make an analogous query against a SQL view, Entity Framework generates SQL referring to *every column* in the view:

```
ViewTypes.Select(rdi => rdi.Name)
```

becomes

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM (SELECT 
      [ViewTypes].[Name] AS [Name], 
      ... every other column in my view ...
      FROM [dbo].[ViewReferenceDataTypes] AS [ViewReferenceDataTypes]) AS [Extent1]
```

I'm sure SQL Server will perform its own optimization to end up ignoring all the columns it doesn't care about, but this still results in a massive block of SQL being sent to the server. (My actual example included a join, which resulted in every column from *several* tables being selected...)

Is there a good reason for Entity Framework to do this? Is there a way to make it *not* do this?

Comment: Do you have LazyLoading enabled?

Comment: @Tico I don't have any navigation properties so I don't think that matters. (If it does matter, my answer is "no idea"!)

Comment: Hum..try Disable it..it won't hurt;

Comment: @Tico I added a `ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before my query and it didn't change anything, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yep. No idea, then =/

Comment: Why do you expect EF to generate good SQL?  ORMs are notorious for the poor SQL they generate, its a trade off for the speed of development and flexibility they offer.

Comment: @Maess That was my initial response when I saw what it generated for my view-join. However, given it generates nice SQL against tables, I'd like to know why it *doesn't* against *views*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework edmx generator uses DefiningQuery element to define entity set based on view, and it explicitly specifies view's SQL query:

```
<EntitySet Name="custview" EntityType="AdventureWorksLTModel.Store.custview">
  <DefiningQuery>SELECT [custview].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
   [custview].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
   [custview].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
   [custview].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName]
   FROM [dbo].[custview] AS [custview]
  </DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

so, the only way EF can apply filtering expression to DefiningQuery is to wrap it with subquery. If you believe it's not efficient for your database, you can manually edit edmx file with in any text editor and specify any query you want.

There's also [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716798%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element that can possibly be [more effective](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2008/12/19/definingquery-versus-queryview.aspx)

Comment: Brilliant! I've managed to find and comment these out and it does indeed shrink my SQL. It looks like EF adds these deliberately in order to fail faster if I try to "add" an item to my view; I suppose it's up to me whether I want smaller SQL instead.